# How to filter the parquet dataset on date range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataset of parquet files partitioned based on the `year` `month` and then `day`. The sample dataset is like

| source_id | loaded_at | participant_id | partition_day | partition_month | partition_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2021-01-02 12:00:00 | B | 2 | 1 | 2021 |
| c | 2021-01-03 12:30:00 | A | 3 | 1 | 2021 |
| d | 2021-01-04 12:45:00 | C | 4 | 1 | 2021 |
| a | 2021-01-02 13:00:00 | E | 2 | 1 | 2021 |
| b | 021-01-03 13:30:00 | A | 3 | 1 | 2021 |
| c | 2021-01-04 13:45:00 | B | 4 | 1 | 2021 |

What is the best way to filter the data based on data range ?

Answer (score 2):

Though i tried multiple approaches, I eventually went with using the below approach

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

start_date = datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2022, 3, 31)
num_of_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

df = spark.read.parquet("")\
.where(f"make_date(partition_year, partition_month, partition_day) >= \
                '{start_date}'\
            AND make_date(partition_year, partition_month, partition_day) <= \
                '{end_date}'")
```

This gives a result with no addition overhead.

The details of all approaches is available @ https://sharathmysore.hashnode.dev/date-range-query-on-partitioned-date-columns-on-pyspark

Comment: Hi Sharath. Looked at your blog - did the approach 2 perform better than tha approach 3? Do you have results of any perf comparison?

Comment: @sushantsha I don't have the perf number but we went with approach 2 since its a wrapper available directly in spark.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming yout loaded_at is a date filed that you used to partition this .

convert the timestamp to unix timstamp ,

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

you can convert the date string to timestamp
unix_timestamp(df["loaded_at"])

and then apply filters

```
df=df.filter(df["loaded_at"]>='2021-01-01')
```

or

```
df=df.filter ( (unix_timestamp(df["loaded_at"])>=unix_timestamp('2021-01-01')) && (unix_timestamp(df["loaded_at"])<unix_timestamp('2021-01-05'))
```

you can also filter based on SQL type

```
df.filter ( "loaded_at BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-03' " )
```

Comment: I would want to filter on the `partition_day` `partition_month` & `partition_year` since its not coupled with underlying column used for partitioning